# Is it possible to dispatch a message in the topic to only a certain queues while using virtual topic?

Tags: activemq-classic

A message sent to a virtual topic will be dispatched to every queue named as "Consumer.*.VirtualTopic.", is it possible that such messages will only be dispatched to a certain queues that match a condition , instead of all the queues that map to the virtual topic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know up front that there are only going to be a set number of consumers/queues, you can use composite destinations instead of virtual ones and use `filteredDestination` blocks to make routing decisions based on message headers.

```
<destinationInterceptors>
  <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    <virtualDestinations>
      <compositeQueue name="orders">
        <forwardTo>
          <filteredDestination selector="odd = 'yes'" queue="orders.odd"/>
          <queue physicalName="orders.accounting" />
          <queue physicalName="orders.warehouse" />
          <queue physicalName="orders.crm" />
        </forwardTo>
      </compositeQueue>
    </virtualDestinations>
  </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

For more complex routing decisions you should consider using an external routing engine such as Apache Camel.

Comment: Consumers could be added into broker in runtime, so I guess composite destinations is not an option. I'll look into camel instead.Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Just a thought, you could look at the problem sideways. If you have only a small set of filters, send messages to different virtual destinations - each corresponding to a different filter condition.